# Negative index value?

Tags: jquery

Consider this JavaScript:

```
var number = $(".linksMiniImages a").index(this);
alert (number);
```

Alert shows `-1` when I click on a link.

What could be wrong?

Comment: what's `this`, in what context is your code called?

Comment: What do you want to do? Have you read the documentation?

Comment: -1 means it's not found.  What is `this`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run that `this` will be referring to something other than the `a` element, most likely `window`.

If you simply remove the `this` from your code it should behave as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/Zikes/2kFJt/

Alternatively, this may be what you're after:
http://jsfiddle.net/Zikes/frBa8/1/

Comment: Hmmm, but would this work if I have several links? I just want to know the index of the link that has been clicked?

Comment: @user637364 the second example will do that, yes.

Comment: I discovered that I missed the a in the click function! Thanks for the help!